How to remove all rows that were created through document fragment?
I have created a document fragment that dynamically creates html rows and put all of this within a function, but every time this function is called it creates the rows again, I want to know how to delete these rows before creating.
Pls see my code below:
let getLocation = () => {
  $.ajax({
    url: "./libs/php/getAllLocations.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
      console.log("Locations");
      console.log(result);

      if (result["status"]["code"] == 200) {
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

        for (i = 0; i < result["data"].length; i++) {
          locationData = [];

          locationData["id"] = result["data"][i]["id"];
          locationData["location"] = result["data"][i]["name"];
          var row = document.createElement("tr");
          var loc_name = document.createElement("td");
          var loc_button = document.createElement("td");

          var edit_button = document.createElement("button");
          var edit_button_i = document.createElement("i");
          var delete_button = document.createElement("button");
          var delete_button_i = document.createElement("i");

          edit_button.setAttribute("type", "button");
          edit_button.setAttribute("data-bs-toggle", "modal");
          edit_button.setAttribute("data-bs-target", "#editLocationModal");
          edit_button.setAttribute("data-id", locationData["id"]);
          delete_button.setAttribute("type", "button");
          delete_button.setAttribute("id", "deleteLocationBtn");
          delete_button.setAttribute("data-id", locationData["id"]);
          delete_button.setAttribute(
            "data-name",
            locationData["location"].replace(/\s+/g, "-"),
          );

          loc_name.classList = "align-middle w-100 text-nowrap";
          loc_button.classList = "text-end btn-group";
          edit_button.classList = "btn btn-primary btn-sm";
          delete_button.classList = "btn btn-primary btn-sm";
          edit_button_i.classList = "fa-solid fa-pencil fa-fw";
          delete_button_i.classList = "fa-solid fa-trash fa-fw";
          row.setAttribute("id", locationData["id"]);

          var loc_name_text = document.createTextNode(locationData["location"]);
          loc_name.append(loc_name_text);
          loc_button.append(edit_button);
          loc_button.append(delete_button);
          edit_button.append(edit_button_i);
          delete_button.append(delete_button_i);
          row.append(loc_name);
          row.append(loc_button);

          frag.append(row);
        }

        $("#fetchLocation").append(frag);
      }
    },

    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.error("AJAX Error:", textStatus, errorThrown);
    },
  });
};

And the refresh button code:
$("#refreshBtn").click(function () {
  getLocation();
});


To solve your current issue, you need to delete the previous rows before appending the new ones. But you didn't delete previous rows and only added new rows. To delete previous rows, I added one line.
$('#fetchLocation').empty();

This is full code.
et getLocation = () => {
  $.ajax({
    url: "./libs/php/getAllLocations.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
      console.log("Locations");
      console.log(result);

      if (result["status"]["code"] == 200) {
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

        // Clear existing rows before adding new ones.
        $('#fetchLocation').empty();

        for (i = 0; i < result["data"].length; i++) {
          locationData = [];

          locationData["id"] = result["data"][i]["id"];
          locationData["location"] = result["data"][i]["name"];
          var row = document.createElement("tr");
          var loc_name = document.createElement("td");
          var loc_button = document.createElement("td");

          var edit_button = document.createElement("button");
          var edit_button_i = document.createElement("i");
          var delete_button = document.createElement("button");
          var delete_button_i = document.createElement("i");

          edit_button.setAttribute("type", "button");
          edit_button.setAttribute("data-bs-toggle", "modal");
          edit_button.setAttribute("data-bs-target", "#editLocationModal");
          edit_button.setAttribute("data-id", locationData["id"]);
          delete_button.setAttribute("type", "button");
          delete_button.setAttribute("id", "deleteLocationBtn");
          delete_button.setAttribute("data-id", locationData["id"]);
          delete_button.setAttribute(
            "data-name",
            locationData["location"].replace(/\s+/g, "-"),
          );

          loc_name.classList = "align-middle w-100 text-nowrap";
          loc_button.classList = "text-end btn-group";
          edit_button.classList = "btn btn-primary btn-sm";
          delete_button.classList = "btn btn-primary btn-sm";
          edit_button_i.classList = "fa-solid fa-pencil fa-fw";
          delete_button_i.classList = "fa-solid fa-trash fa-fw";
          row.setAttribute("id", locationData["id"]);

          var loc_name_text = document.createTextNode(locationData["location"]);
          loc_name.append(loc_name_text);
          loc_button.append(edit_button);
          loc_button.append(delete_button);
          edit_button.append(edit_button_i);
          delete_button.append(delete_button_i);
          row.append(loc_name);
          row.append(loc_button);

          frag.append(row);
        }

        $("#fetchLocation").append(frag);
      }
    },

    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.error("AJAX Error:", textStatus, errorThrown);
    },
  });
};


Hi, @JenaidaBarreto. so my answer solved your issue correctly, right?

yes completely, i was doing $('#fetchLocation').reset(); and it was not working, but what you mentioned $('#fetchLocation').empty(); worked 200%
